# expand search region in MKlocalSearch mapkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mklocalsearch

I am using mapkit and MKLocalSearch to search for business locations within the users current area. However the region doesnt seem to be as large as I need and some business locations will not show up in my search unless I set my current location to closer to that business. I would like the span to be 75 miles, any suggestions on how to expand the region in my code? I am new to using mapkit and have been unable to find anything helpful. Heres my search methods.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

// Cancel any previous searches.
[localSearch cancel];

// Perform a new search.
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text;
request.region = self.mapView.region;

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error){

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    if (error != nil) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Map Error",nil)
                                    message:[error localizedDescription]
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil) otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }

    if ([response.mapItems count] == 0) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No Results",nil)
                                    message:nil
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil) otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }

    results = response;

    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [results.mapItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {

static NSString *IDENTIFIER = @"SearchResultsCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IDENTIFIER];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:IDENTIFIER];
}

MKMapItem *item = results.mapItems[indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = item.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.placemark.addressDictionary[@"Street"];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];

MKMapItem *item = results.mapItems[indexPath.row];


[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:item.placemark.location.coordinate animated:YES];

[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate,
120701, 120701);
// 120701 meters is 75 miles
```

or if you have a location already:

```
request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
120701, 120701);
```

Setting the search region independently like this allows you to search large areas without expanding the map.

Comment: any way to make this world-wide?